# sending bulk emails in java using threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, email, sendmail, bulk

hey i had to send bulk mails through Java. First i done it through smtpserver i was able to send the mails but it was slow. 
So i searched and used threads to achieve this.but what the treads are doing is they are sending a fresh request to smtp server every time  that always wants to connect and authenticate every time.
    Now My question is how can request the server connect and authenticate only once
[Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
transport.connect(host, port, username, password);]

and how to call send message multiple times? [transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));]
what i tried is as below

```
public class EmailService implements Runnable{
     String customerMail="";
     String  messageType="";
     String subject="";
     String message="";
     int customerMailId=0;
     int campaignId=0;




    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("inside thread");
            this.sendEmail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setParameters(String customerMail,String messageType,String subject,String message,int customerMailId,int campaignId) {
        this.customerMail=customerMail;
        this.messageType=messageType;
        this.subject=subject;
        this.message=message;
        this.customerMailId=customerMailId;
        this.campaignId=campaignId;
    }
final String username = "**********";
        final String password = "*******";
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
      String password = "******";
        int port = 465;

        public void sendEmail() {
        System.out.println("inside emailservice");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.username", username);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol.", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
            transport.connect(host, port, username, password);

            if (messageType.equals("TO")) {

                    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
                    msg.setSubject(subject);
                    System.out.println("inside to method");
                    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, customerMail);
                    int mailingId = customerMailId;

                    message = message.replaceAll(".jpeg", ".jpeg?&campId=" + campaignId + "&opId=" + mailingId);
                    message = message.replaceAll(".JPEG", ".jpeg?&campId=" + campaignId + "&opId=" + mailingId);
                    message = message.replaceAll(".jpg", ".jpg?&campId=" + campaignId + "&opId=" + mailingId);
                    message = message.replaceAll(".JPG", ".jpg?&campId=" + campaignId + "&opId=" + mailingId);
                    message = message.replaceAll(".png", ".png?&campId=" + campaignId + "&opId=" + mailingId);
                    message = message.replaceAll(".PNG", ".PNG?&campId=" + campaignId + "&opId=" + mailingId);
                    String msgBody = "<a href=http://wmail.*****.in/?&campId=" + campaignId
                            + "&clkId=" + mailingId + ">" + message + "</a>" + "<br><br>" + "<b>To stop receiving these emails please" + "<a  href=http://wmail.****.in?&campId=" + campaignId
                            + "&unsubsId=" + mailingId + ">" + " click here </a>" + "to unsubscribe.</b>";
                    msg.setContent(msgBody, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));   }
            System.out.println("inside sucees");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void MailSender(List<NameEmailRecord> receiverEmail, String messageType, String subject, String message, int campaignId)
    {
        String mail="";
        int mailId=0;       
          for (NameEmailRecord ner : receiverEmail) {
           mail=ner.getMailingEmail();
           mailId=ner.getMailingEmailId();
            EmailService es = new EmailService();            es.setParameters(mail,messageType,subject,message,mailId,campaignId);
            Thread t = new Thread(es);
            t.start();       
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it just tha you want *all* the sends to be done asynchronosly in *one extra thread* or do you in fact want *several* threads? And... Please share some code what you tried so far and... welcome to Stack Ovverflow :-)

Comment: my code as far now is

Answer (score 0):

SMTP connections happen on a Socket. So for one connection to any SMTP server it's one-at-a-time for sending messages (that is individual messages, every message could have many recipients).

I guess in your case that means finding a good compromise between cost-of-login and emails-per-thread.

For sending multiple emails (sent through same SMTP server) through one Transport, you simply create a transport and reuse it, invoking sendMessage for each message to be sent.

Comment: public void MailSender(List<NameEmailRecord> receiverEmail, String messageType, String subject, String message, int campaignId)                  {  EmailService es1=new EmailService();  es1.openMail();                       for (NameEmailRecord ner : receiverEmail) {                                                  EmailService es = new EmailService();             es.setParameters(receiverEmail.getToMail(),receiverEmail.getToMailId(),messageType,subject,message,mailId,campaignId); //to set parameters
 Thread t = new Thread(es);
        t.start();
       }

Comment: here is my run method                                                                       @Override
  public void run() {
        try {
        System.out.println("inside thread");
         this.sendEmail();//this sendEmail method takes care of sending //individual email.as iam running it through thread it is sending multiple //mails at a time
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

Comment: Can you edit your post to include that? Much better to read that way

Comment: now it is working but after sending some mails connection time out error is coming

Comment: this will happen if SMTP connection is inactive for some time. Can you share some code? How do you dispatch the messages to be sent into the threads?

Comment: i am trying to paste code here but it is not in readable format

Comment: transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)); calling this method for every thread to send messages  and before this i am calling transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
            transport.connect(host, port, username, password); this only once

Comment: You can **edit your question**  code formatting works great there ;-). So you have *one* Transport per Thread or *one* Transport overall?

Comment: Then probalby you hit some threshold on tje receiving smtp thinking you're spamming or something alike. You should check with your provider / mail server guys if inhouse.

Comment: jan please see the above code tell me what is wrong

Comment: yes but after sending some emails throwing exception

Comment: Possibly too many connects to your smtp. You should limit no. of threads and have each thread send multiple mails maybe. Do you have local sendmail or where do you send to?

Comment: ya problem is too many connections so i separated the connection part in one method {till transport.connect(host, port, username, password);
}and sendmessage method.per every thread i am sending 75 mails.the problem is it is throwing Exception after sending some mails

Comment: connection closed by remote host